# SQL Select where user1 has more than one and user2 has none

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my Query to find id's for userid 2, I want to run a query that finds entries where userid=2 and amount>1 AND userid 1 has none of that id

```
SELECT id, amount FROM collection WHERE userid='2' AND amount>1
```

I'm not sure how to do an if statement inside a SQL query, but there has to be a way to easily do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want The list of users having user ID = 2 and amount > 1. This list should ignore the records where ID is not in user ID = 1

**Sample Input/Ouput:**

```
ID UserID Amount Returned?
1   2     0       No (Amount 0)
2   2      10     Yes
3   1      10 
3   2      5      (No, since ID =3 exists with Userid = 1)
```

Below Query should help you with it.

```
SELECT C.ID, C.AMOUNT 
FROM COLLECTION C
WHERE C.USERID = 2 AND C.AMOUNT > 1 
      AND C.ID NOT IN 
              (  SELECT D.ID 
                 FROM COLLECTION D
                 WHERE D.USERID = 1
              );
```

### **[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/517d1/4)**

Answer (score 0):

*"where userid=2 and amount>1 AND userid 1 has none of that id"*

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, amount 
FROM collection c
WHERE c.userid = '2' 
  AND c.amount > 1
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
      SELECT 1 FROM collection c2
      WHERE c2.userid = '1'
       AND  c.id = c2.id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, amount 
FROM collection 
WHERE userid='2' AND amount > 1 AND 
NOT id in (SELECT id FROM collection WHERE userid='1' AND amount > 1)
```

I'm not sure this is how your database is working, but this is how I would've solved it.